# AWS launch configuration not showing updated IAM role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am creating an Aws launch configuration for codedeploy from code commit and it does not show the IAM role to chose. I have created a new role and it does not show up in the launch configuration option

Comment: A *Launch Configuration* is normally associated with Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling groups. Is this the configuration you are using? If so, when creating the role, make sure to select **Amazon EC2** as the Service Role (with the description: *Allows EC2 instances to call AWS services on your behalf*).

Comment: @guru - Did you ever figure this out? It's driving me crazy today!

Comment: I think the reason was the role I created did not have access to attach AWSDeployFullAccess to it. I had to ask the admin to provide that then I was able to see it. But it is annoying as the UI is not intuitive. try it and let me know

Comment: In my case, which might be different than yours, my Role lacked an Instance Profile ARN, I had to create an object of type AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile.

Comment: InstanceProfile worked for me.